# subprocess.Popen behaves differently if exe is located in same directory as .py script

Tags: python

If I run my script, 'test.py' in the same directory that the silent_install folder resides in (c:\users\test_user\desktop\dist), the program behaves differently than if I run it with the silent_install folder outside of that directory. The program keeps looping without ever finishing if I run it like this.

```
    #test.py

    def proc_check(proc):
        exists = []
        for p in psutil.process_iter():
            if p.name() == proc:
                exists.append(p)
        if not exists:
            return False
        return True

    #uninstall program silently (doesn't work)
    while os.path.exists(r"c:\program files\foobar"):    
        subprocess.Popen([r"c:\users\test_user\desktop\dist\silent_install\setup.exe",
                         "/s",
                         "/f1c:\\users\\test_user\\desktop\\dist\\silent_install\\uninstall.iss"])

        #check if setup is running before continuing
        while True:
            if proc_check("setup.exe") == False:
                break
```

However, if I run it this way instead (with the silent_install folder outside of c:\users\test_user\desktop\dist), the program behaves the way I want it to, the silent uninstaller actually works.

```
#uninstall program silently (works like this)
while os.path.exists(r"c:\program files\foobar"):    
    subprocess.Popen([r"c:\users\test_user\desktop\silent_install\setup.exe",
                     "/s",
                     "/f1c:\\users\\test_user\\desktop\\silent_install\\uninstall.iss"])`
```

Does anyone know why it's doing this?

Comment: I see two loops in the first part of your code. Which loop is getting stuck?

Comment: I'm confused by your two code blocks. The loop in the second block appears to be exactly identical to the loop in the first block, but you seem to be trying to draw a contrast between them. It's unclear what is supposed to be different between the two versions of the code.

Comment: I'd also suggest using a different `subprocess` function rather than using `Popen` and then trying to check if the program is still running. Something like [`subprocess.check_call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) is probably better, since it waits for the called program to end and will raise an exception if its return code is not zero.

Comment: @LeopoldVonBuschLight The first 'while' loop is getting stuck. The loop never breaks.

Comment: @Blckknght You're right, they are almost exactly identical. However, if you look closely the only thing that changes is the directories: \desktop\dist\silent_install\ >>> \desktop\silent_install\